# Should writing to the GUI be kept to a minimum?

Tags: c#

I set up a windows form with a textbox, and two buttons, here is the click event for the buttons:

```
private int numberOfIterations = 1000;
private void WriteToGuiManyTimesButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TestTextBox.Text = string.Empty;
    DateTime startTime = DateTime.Now;
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfIterations; i++)
    {
        TestTextBox.Text += "s";
    }
    DateTime endTime = DateTime.Now;
    TestLabel.Text = (endTime.Ticks - startTime.Ticks).ToString();
}

private void WriteToGuiOnceButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TestTextBox.Text = string.Empty;
    DateTime startTime = DateTime.Now;
    string s = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfIterations; i++)
    {
        s += "s";
    }
    TestTextBox.Text = s;
    DateTime endTime = DateTime.Now;
    TestLabel.Text = (endTime.Ticks - startTime.Ticks).ToString();
}
```

The end result is the same, the textbox has 1000 lots of "s".

However, if you prepare the string in memory, then write it to the Textbox, it only takes 9985 ticks, but if you write to the Textbox each time, it takes 1222285 ticks.

Is this because writing to TextBox.Text takes longer than writing to a variable in memory, if so, why?

Comment: Constant re-painting of the TextBox

Comment: The best solution is to use StringBuilder for itterations

Comment: Yes but StringBuilder doesn't help me in this situation since my goal is to find out why writing to the GUI is slow, not to use efficient code. If I used a StringBuilder, then I'd have to use it in both button click events to keep the variables controlled. How can I write to the GUI many times using a for loop AND use a StringBuilder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason writing multiple times to `Textbox.Text` is much slower is that it is a property. The property excutes code each time it is written, potentially firing all kinds of events, such as repainting as Dmitry suggests.

Altering a string in memory simply creates a new string with the added character which seems to be much faster. Again as Dmitry suggests, using a StringBuilder would be the best choice since that would not result in a new string object being created for each modification.

Answer (score 1):

It takes a lot of time for the `TextBox` to be ***re-painting*** in each loop itteration;
however constant `string` ***re-creating*** in `s += "s"` is not a good choice either.
Use `StringBuilder` as a buffer:

```
private void WriteToGuiManyTimesButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  DateTime startTime = DateTime.Now;

  StringBuilder Sb = new StringBuilder();

  for (int i = 0; i < numberOfIterations; ++i) {
    Sb.Append("s");
  }

  TestTextBox.Text = Sb.ToString();

  DateTime endTime = DateTime.Now;
  TestLabel.Text = (endTime.Ticks - startTime.Ticks).ToString();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However I already knew that it takes a lot of time for the Textbox to be repainting in each loop. I wanted to find out why this is, not that StringBuilder is better.